# Getting Emacs to recognize analogous Unicode characters as equivalent when searching

Tags: search, unicode

In most contexts, like Firefox of MS Office, if I have text that says, "It’s my birthday" (where the apostrophe has Unicode decimal code 8217) and I search for "It's my birthday" (with a simple apostrophe, decimal code 39) the search matches despite the fact that the two apostrophes are different Unicode characters. However, in Emacs text-mode, the two don't match. Is there a way I can get Emacs's search to consider the two apostrophes the same?

I'm using `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.porkrind.org` on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. I'm using a graphic display.

Comment: Emacs does this now, in development snapshots of Emacs 25 (Emacs 25 is not yet released). This "character folding" was introduced a few months ago, and it is turned on by default.

Comment: @Drew, I tried with this text from the question and it doesn't seem to work in Emacs trunk.

Comment: Provide an exact recipe of what you tried. Note too that you must search using the "canonical" member of the equivalence class of chars - e.g., plain ASCII apostrophe. Or else you need to use code such as what [I provided](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-09/msg00456.html), which lets you search using any of the class members for any of the other members of the class.

Comment: @Drew, not sure if you're addressing me or Mark, but I'm just doing a standard incremental search. My query uses the canonical apostrophe.

Comment: I was addressing you (no "@" sign). In any case, it works fine for me (and for others). But it's quite possible that what "**it**" is is something different for each of us. Hard to know, as you don't provide a recipe or cite a particular build (e.g. `M-x emacs-version`). You don't say anything about whether you are using a graphic display or only a terminal, what your platform is, or anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: Unrelated to this discussion, but it's always better to use the **@** sign for clarity. *In this case, I didn't use it because it's sort of a PSA.* If there are 3 or more people in the discussion (including the post OP (could be question or answer)), that **@** reference will be retained. If there are just 2 (or less) people in the discussion, stackexchange will remove that reference notation automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Drew's comment I believe the answer is that the feature I'm seeking is available in Emacs 25 (which has yet to be released as of 2015-09-27), but I'm using Emacs 24.